# What Formula to use for this task?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So for a recent interview I was given a set of tasks to carry out on a workbook. I'm now going through the tasks that I couldn't understand or complete. I was wondering if anyone could help me through it or know a site maybe better suited for this sort of thing?

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBAFs.png)

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKUpk.png)

Answer (score 0):

So here's the original formula:

```
=IF(E2="national","10",IF(E2="local","25",""))
```

And they want you to reprice local calls so they're 5p per minute with a price cap of 25.

Easiest way to do that is to nest another IF statement:

```
=IF(E2="national","10",IF(E2="local",IF(K2>5,"25",K2*5),""))
```

In the future, please write a question title that others will be able to easily search for when they have the same issue.

Comment: A couple of the rows are giving a value error with that formula - 441440759447 Dec-18 48BDB29F-E231-48D2-95AE-940893284BD6 Landline Hosted Voice Local off net United Kingdom - Haverhill 30/09/2018 15:57:00 262.00 4.366666667 £0.077 1.76